# How to automate splitting google sheet columns when Jira Cloud data is imported

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, jira

I am attempting to fully automate a data pull from Jira into Google Sheets using the Jira cloud add-on for Google Sheets.

I am having trouble as when doing a Jira cloud pull, it creates a column in the sheet for each "value" you are pulling out of Jira.

I want to:

- place a formula on a particular column that will always be the same data, but often includes data separated by semi-colons.
- have the data in specific columns automatically split into 2 columns next to each other when the scheduled weekly job runs to pull the data.

I am unsure how to do this as the data pulled overwrites the entire sheet (including removal of an additional column since the import didn't have that extra value/column when pulling the data).

You can have conditional formatting in place and it is not overwritten by the data import, but if you were to have a formula typed into a specific cell it is overwritten by the data in the import.

Comment: You would have to put the formula in a different tab, then use a combination of split / index to get the data you want.  If you provide an example, we can help with an answer.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.